# Retrieve data's component from custom directive

Tags: vue.js

So I want to bind style using a directive since I need to test a value send to the element.

```
<div v-portrait="photo.portrait"></div>
```

The thing is I need to access a `data()` of my component but I don't get how since `this` is out of scope.

```
directives: {
    portrait: {
        bind: function (el, binding) {
            if(binding.value == true){
                console.log(this); //undefined
                el.height = (this.rowHeight)+ 'px';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So how could I retrieve `this.rowHeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind` has a 3rd argument, it's vnode. You can access Vue instance through this paramteter

```
bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
  if(binding.value == true){
    console.log(this); //undefined
    el.height = (vnode.context.rowHeight)+ 'px';
  }            
 }
```

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments)

Comment: Beautifull thank you ! I issed that in the documentation :/